Recessed lights in lath and plaster ceiling of 1920s home
I am trying to install recessed lights in a 1925 old home. It has lath and plaster ceiling. I have two concern:

How to cut a clean hole and avoid crumbled edges?


Normal Wood hole saw would get dull really fast. So shall I use some carbide bit or something used for cutting tiles?


Can there be asbestos in the plaster?

